Is there a relation between dimensions of source, target and fiber of surjective morphism of possibly reducible varieties?
Let's define the dimension of a quasi-projective variety to be the maximum dimension of it's irreducible components. If $X\to Y$ is a surjective morphism of irreducible varieties such that the all the fibers have the same dimension $k$, then it follows from "generic dimension of fibers" that $\dim(X)=k+\dim(Y)$. I have two questions:

If $X\to Y$ is surjective but only $Y$ is assumed to be irreducible and all the fibers still have the same dimension $k$, is it true that $\dim(X)=k+\dim(Y)$? If not, does someone have a counter example?

If $X\to Y$ is surjective and neither $X$ nor $Y$ is assumed to be irreducible and all the fibers still have the same dimension $k$, is it true that $\dim(X)=k+\dim(Y)$? If not, does someone have a counter example?

What if we add the assumption that the fibers are irreducible in questions 1 and 2?


Any help is appreciated!
